# Finding the intersection of two parametrised functions

Tags: equation-solving, parametric-functions

I have a Mathematica Notebook for drawing an evolute (involute) like this:

```
a := 1
ex := a Cos[t] + a t Sin[t]
ey := a Sin[t] - a t Cos[t]
b := 1.5
cx := b Cos[t]
cy := b Sin[t]
c := 1
ix := c Cos[t]
iy := c Sin[t]
ParametricPlot[{{ex, ey}, {cx, cy}, {ix, iy}}, {t, 0, π/2}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Evolute", PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image: Output Image]

I would like to find the intersection between the circle segment `{cx, cy}` and the evolute `{ex, ey}`. All of my attempts have gone terribly wrong.

Comment: There won't be a good closed form solution, since the underlying equations are transcendental. Will you be okay with an approximation?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: @J.M., sure. This is a architectural question for designing a 400m track&field course, here the waterfall starting line for the 1.000m to 10.000m races. Absolute accuracy is not necessary. Thank you!

Comment: Just for everybody's clarification: the parametric equations implied by the pair `{ex, ey}` are the *involute of a circle*; that is, the circle implied by `{ix, iy}` is the evolute of the curve described by `{ex, ey}`.

Comment: @J.M. Actually there are closed form solutions such as `{Cos[Sqrt[5]/2] + 
  1/2 Sqrt[5] Sin[Sqrt[5]/2], -(1/2) Sqrt[5] Cos[Sqrt[5]/2] + 
  Sin[Sqrt[5]/2]`. But yeah, there was no compelling reason to expect them, at least nothing that is obvious to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a = 1;
ex[t_] = a Cos[t] + a t Sin[t];
ey[t_] = a Sin[t] - a t Cos[t];
b = 3/2;
cx[t_] = b Cos[t];
cy[t_] = b Sin[t];
c = 1;
ix[t_] = c Cos[t];
iy[t_] = c Sin[t];

pt = {ex[t1], ey[t1]} /.
  FindRoot[
   {ex[t1] == cx[t2], ey[t1] == cy[t2]},
   {{t1, π/4}, {t2, π/4}}]

(*  {1.44283, 0.410157}  *)

ParametricPlot[
 {{ex[t], ey[t]}, {cx[t], cy[t]}, {ix[t], iy[t]}},
 {t, 0, π/2},
 PlotLabel -> "Evolute",
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Tooltip[Point[pt], pt]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah yes - I do understand this. Good approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I beg to differ :)

Using Bob Hanlon's set-up, an ***exact*** solution, numerically equal to Feyre's:

```
Block[{a, b, c, cy, ey, cx, ex, ix, iy},
 a = 1;
 ex[t_] = a Cos[t] + a t Sin[t];
 ey[t_] = a Sin[t] - a t Cos[t];
 b = 3/2;
 cx[t_] = b Cos[t];
 cy[t_] = b Sin[t];
 c = 1;
 ix[t_] = c Cos[t];
 iy[t_] = c Sin[t];

 sol = Solve[
  {ex[t1] == cx[t2], ey[t1] == cy[t2], 0 < t1 < Pi/2, 0 < t2 < Pi/2},
  {t1, t2}, Method -> Reduce]
 ];
sol
N[sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Remarks: To get the intersection of two curves, you need two parameters as the other answers show.  The best way, imo, is to make the expressions explicit functions of the parameters (but one could use `ReplaceAll`: `ex /. t -> t1`, etc.).  Solving transcendental equations exactly is often not possible, but when trying, it helps to limit the domains of the variables and try [`Reduce[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html).

Comment: Hah, nice! But as you say, we are not always so lucky.

Comment: @J.M. And given the application, `FindRoot[]` seems a better general strategy.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Wow. One lives to learn...thank you.

Comment: I like low-level solutions when approximating, force of habit.

Comment: You just talked yourself out of 15 rep ;)

Comment: You get a cleaner form for `t2` if you use `FullSimplify` as part of definition for `sol`

Comment: @Feyre: Lucky me :)

Comment: @Feyre If rep were bitcoin.... But it's better for the site & its users if the better answer is accepted.  I really only intended my answer as a sidelight on *Mathematica's* symbolic capabilities, given that it had been mentioned.  For building things, usually only a few digits of accuracy are needed, and numerics generally beat symbolics in such a case.

Answer (score 6):

Redefine with different variables:

```
cx := b Cos[u]
cy := b Sin[u]
```

Minimize, like @J.M. said, this won't give exact results.

```
NMinimize[Sqrt[(cy - ey)^2 + (cx - ex)^2], {u, t}, Reals]
```

> `{6.59602*10^-10, {u -> 0.276965, t -> 1.11803}}`

```
{ex, ey} /. {u -> 0.27696531800957025`, t -> 1.1180339888944713`}
{cx, cy} /. {u -> 0.27696531800957025`, t -> 1.1180339888944713`}
```

> `{1.44283, 0.410157}`
>
> `{1.44283, 0.410157}`

Returning to single parameter:

```
Show[ParametricPlot[{{ex, ey}, {cx, cy}, {ix, iy}}, {t, 0, π/2}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Evolute", PlotLegends -> "Expressions"], 
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], 
   Point[{1.4428344948227565`, 0.41015682473030135`}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is the approach I use when `FindRoot[]` & `NSolve[]` fail, or I have no idea of a good initial search point.  If I did have a starting point, I would try `FindMinimum[]` first. (+1 a while ago, now).